# How to access JavaScript variable in laravel route

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

how can access JavaScript variable in laravel blade route

this is my code:

```
'{{ URL::signedRoute('downloadvideo', ['video_Id' => videoId]) }}'
```

and the error is:

```
Use of undefined constant videoId - assumed 'videoId'
```

Comment: You can't use JavaScript variables at this moment because this JavaScript is client-side whereas Blade templating is server-side. Edit and add more details if you want more help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
url: "{{url('')}}/your_url/"+your_variable,
```